# Angular forms submit button doesn't work when I click on it

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I use Angular forms for updating data, but the submit button doesn't work and the data doesn't get updated even though the update method in the back end is working well. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my angular component 
HTML :

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div>
    <label for="title">
      Title
    </label>
    <input id="title" type="text" [(ngModel)]="project.title" name="title">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="description">
      Description
    </label>
    <input id="description" type="text" [(ngModel)]="project.description" name="description">
  </div>

  <button class="button" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

typescript :

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ProjectService} from "../project.service";
import {Project} from "../project";
import {Subscription} from "rxjs";
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-edit',
  templateUrl: './project-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-edit.component.css']
})
export class ProjectEditComponent implements OnInit {
project: Project;
private sub : Subscription;
constructor(
          private projectService: ProjectService,
          private route: ActivatedRoute,
          private router: Router
) {

}

ngOnInit() {
this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  let id = +params['id'];
  this.projectService.getProject(id)
    .then(project => this.project = project);
});
}

onSubmit() {
  this.updateProject();
}

updateProject() {
 this.projectService.updateProject(this.project.id, this.project)
  .then(pr => this.project = new Project())
  }

}
```

Here's the projectService with the updateProject function :

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Project} from "./project";

import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080';

  constructor(private  http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getProjects(): Promise<Project[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/api/project/')
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response as Project[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getProject(id: number): Promise<Project> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/api/project/' + id)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response as Project)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  createProject(project: Project) {

    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/api/projects', project);

  }

  updateProject(id: number, newProjectData: Project): Promise<Project> {
    return this.http.put(this.baseUrl+'/api/projects' + id,newProjectData)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response as Project)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  deleteProject(id: number) {

    return this.http.delete(this.baseUrl+'/api/projects' + id);

  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('Some error occured', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

Comment: It is hard to know with this example. Do you have a stackblitz that shows the problem? If not, when you click the button, are you sure your ngSubmit code is not getting called? It looks correct with what you have provided.

Comment: try to add this to your form tag and try again
`
  <form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" #f="ngForm">
`
if you can provide a stackblitz it will be great

Comment: this.project = new Project()? so you're not doing anything with the response in your component? Debug steps (in order): is project set OnInit? is onSubmit called? is api called via updateProject - see network tab? is return data what you expected - can use .pipe(tap(console.log)) after `http.put` and finally back in component are you using response as you intended.

Comment: What do you mean by data doesn't get updated? You've passed the data to the API and then re-assigned the project variable a new instance, so basically it'll assign default values to that variable.

Comment: Hi, When you say submit button doesn't work do you mean its not working with in the user interface or does it not fire the HTTP request or does the data that you have sent via HTTP is not updated somewhere in the back end? Do you see any errors when you hit the submit button?

Comment: @observingstream yes I'm sure. my ngSumbit code is not getting called.

Comment: @RR1112 its not working in the user interface and it does not fire the http request.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nutvqv ... submit is called based on your template assuming project is set. Please check project set OnInit.

Comment: @AndrewAllen thank you. It actually worked. The submit button is working but my database still doesn't get updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **ProjectEditComponent** initialize your `project` object. Something like this:

```
project: Project = {
    title: "",
    description: ""
};
```